# Page Over-flow from Text Input Field

Tags: jquery, html, css

After using the `Tag-It` JQuery plug-in for my site, which turns text inputs into tags in an un-ordered list element. The problem is that I've set the text input to a fixed width, but when the list has enough items in it, the page grows in width too. The page width shouldn't change, and you should be able to look through the list by scrolling horizontally. I've tried setting the `<body>`'s `overflow-x` to `hidden`, as well as using a `site-wrapper div`.

Issue can be seen [here](https://beta.focustime.ca/dashboard2.php?#) after clicking the "Check-In Now" button

Comment: You should provide a minimal code example attached to your question, not as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question properly. But the 'page' is not growing in my Chrome. The bounding box outside the tags input is growing. The Tags library is inserting additional space next to the rendered tags for typing the new tag. See the image - Is this your problem?

[image]